# How to create a filter using bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to create a filter (image shown below) using bootstrap tabs and jQuery but I don't know how to get the value from the 2 select options and applying to the search button.

What I need is get the value from the 2 select boxes and apply that to the search button so that the content will be displayed below.

See the image below.

[image: FILER]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <select id="mySelect">
        <option data-target="#home">2017</option>
        <option data-target="#profile">2018</option>
        <option data-target="#messages">2019</option>
        <option data-target="#settings">2020</option>
    </select>
    <select id="month">
        <option data-target="#home">Jan</option>
        <option data-target="#profile">feb</option>
        <option data-target="#messages">March</option>
        <option data-target="#settings">April</option>
    </select>
    <button> search </button>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            Div 1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            Div 2
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
            Div 3
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
            Div 4
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $('#mySelect').on('change', function(e) {
            var $optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            $optionSelected.tab('show')
        });
        $('#month').on('change', function(e) {
            var $optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            $optionSelected.tab('show')
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Post CODE as well as your pictures

Comment: Hi @mplungjan thank you for replying but I need when I click on the search button I need to display my content

Comment: Sure. But we cannot guess what that means without some code. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Ok will give the code snippet

Comment: @mplungjan I have posted a sample code

Comment: And what actions should result in what expected output?

Comment: I need to display the content below by getting the values of the 2 select box applying those values to the search button so that the content will be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <select id="mySelect">
        <option data-target="#home">2017</option>
        <option data-target="#profile">2018</option>
        <option data-target="#messages">2019</option>
        <option data-target="#settings">2020</option>
    </select>
    <select id="month">
        <option data-target="#home">Jan</option>
        <option data-target="#profile">feb</option>
        <option data-target="#messages">March</option>
        <option data-target="#settings">April</option>
    </select>
    <button> search </button>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            Div 1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            Div 2
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
            Div 3
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
            Div 4
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $('#mySelect').on('change', function(e) {
            var $optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            $optionSelected.tab('show')
        });
        $('#month').on('change', function(e) {
            var $optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            $optionSelected.tab('show')
        });
        $('button').click(function(){
          $('.tab-pane').hide();
          var year =$('select[id=mySelect] option').filter(':selected').attr('data-target');
          var month =$('select[id=month] option').filter(':selected').attr('data-target');
         //alert("year : "+year+" month: "+ month);
          if(year!=undefined){
         $(year).show();
          }
          if(month!=undefined){
         $(month).show();
          }
         });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bro, please check this. Is it okay as per your requirement? if not please let me know what you want there. definitely, I do it.

Comment: Hi Surendra thank you for replying actually its almost ok there is a small problem with this 
if 2012 Jan it shows div1,
if 2013 feb it shows div2,
and so on

actually, it is to display a magazine corresponding to year and month
what if its 2018 and Jan 
in that condition, it should show no div

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
    console.log($('select#mySelect').val());
     console.log($('select#month').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
        <option data-target="#home">2017</option>
        <option data-target="#profile">2018</option>
        <option data-target="#messages">2019</option>
        <option data-target="#settings">2020</option>
 </select>
  <select id="month">
        <option data-target="#home">Jan</option>
        <option data-target="#profile">feb</option>
        <option data-target="#messages">March</option>
        <option data-target="#settings">April</option>
    </select>
    
<button type="button">Get value</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Kumar thank you for sharing the answer this is not the expected output 
I need to display the content below by getting the values of the 2 select box applying those values to the search button so that the content will be displayed

Comment: which `programming language` you used to search functionality??

Comment: programming language jQuery

Comment: Kumar, I already have content I need to display that one, please :) 
See my code snipped above